# How to pass values from one view to 2 controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am beginner with MVC .net 4 I have doubt regarding:
How to pass values from one view to 2 controllers?

Comment: with model,viewdata,viewbag,tempdata.

Comment: There are many ways, can you post some code to illustrate your particular issue?

Comment: What is "pass values" and why would you want to do that to two controllers? Please put some more effort in your explanation.

Comment: I think form collection ill be better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can pass values from view to controller using form collection or model. U can also pass by using ajax json.